# iOS 11 leftBarButtonItem/rightBarButtonItem location bug

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11

i found **`UINavigationBar.height = 56`** **in iOS11** but `UINavigationBar.height = 44` in lower than iOS 11.

my code is here:

```
UIBarButtonItem *scanButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"scan_code"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(pushScanController)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = scanButton;
```

there is a location bug in iOS11.

As shown in figure：

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your problem is caused by the search bar being bigger rather than something in the buttons.

You may want to try something like:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    [[self.yourSearchBar.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:44.0] setActive:YES]
}
```

Or investigate and implement the iOS 11 search bar changes.

Comment: According to your code , UI shows there are still a little abnormal. 
     Besides, under the VC transfer to another VC , there will be a UINavigationBar splash screen, because of the next VC UINavigationBar.height = 56.  So doing this or not so good.